# What are the two turning tendencies that occur during a steep turn?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag

A question has come up in preparation for a Block exam. what are the two turning tendencies that occur during steep turn? If you know this may you please explain to me, why these tendencies occur.
Cheers !

Comment: "The two turning tendencies"? During a steep turn, the aircraft's track tends to rotate into the turn, the heading tends to rotate along with the track but lag behind it, the pitch tends to decrease (which is to say, the nose tends to go down), and the bank angle tends to get steeper. All four of those tendencies involve a kind of "turning", so I can only guess which two of the four are "the two turning tendencies".

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1):

One of the turning tendencies that occurs during a steep turn is the tendency to over-bank.  This is generally due to the outer wing (wing-up) moving faster thru the air and creating a bit more lift that has to be counter-acted.  A second turning tendency is due to adverse yaw (requiring a bit more rudder during a right hand steep turn).

Here is a link that will help you understand:

[aerodynamics of a steep turn](http://www.boldmethod.com/blog/lists/2018/02/the-aerodynamics-of-a-steep-turn/)

Comment: This type of overbanking tendency is characteristic of medium rather than steep turns. In a very steep turn, the outer wing does almost the same circle as the inner one. The adverse yaw effect is symmetric with respect to left/right; it is due to the drag associated with ailerons. The left turning tendency (on most aircraft) is associated with the engine and has little to do with turns.

Comment: @Zeus- Sorry to disagree, but I have done a lot (probably thousands) of steep (and medium) turns with students in many different types of aircraft.  The over-banking tendency varies in magnitude depending on the a/c but it exists and often requires a bit of opposite aileron to counteract.  Yaw problem is definitely a characteristic of prop driven aircraft (again more noticeable in certain types).  Of course, the same yaw issue is not present in jets, but there are unique handling characteristics in steep turns for all a/c types that are definable if you do a lot of training. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: You probably did 50-60° bank turns. For GA, this is 'steep', but I meant steep as steeper than 60°. With these angles, _this kind_ of overbanking gets smaller. Generally, this effect is rather exaggerated in pilots' minds; even a small un-balance (slip) will have a greater effect in most airplanes. 'Yaw problem' is (at least) two-fold: 'adverse yaw' is due to ailerons and is present even in jets and is not left/right specific; the prop reaction is characteristic of any stage of flight and not specifically a turn; and besides, OP didn't specify GA, which implies the answer should be generic.

Comment: @Zeus - Jets, with perhaps minor exceptions, and some turboprops all have yaw dampers to resolve adverse yaw issues from the pilot perspective during normal ops.  My experience in Boeing Jets and Lears vs light prop a/c has made me understand that adverse yaw is an important pilot-feel topic for light prop a/c and not so much for jets with a yaw damper.  I did assume that the OP was talking about GA and was probably not being tested on banks exceeding 60 degrees.  Could be I was wrong.  I appreciate your comments and perspective.

Answer (score 0):

There are two:  the overbankong tendency as a result of the outboard wing moving faster through the air and generating more lift than the inboard  wing.  The second is the left turning tendency as a result of P-factor, engine torque and spiral slipstream effects on the tailboom and vertical fin, requiring more right rudder to maintain a coordinated turn to the right than to the left.

Comment: This second effect has nothing to do with turns. It demands more right rudder (on most aircraft) even in a straight flight. The effect may marginally increase during the turn due to higher AoA and RPM, but it's still the same effect.

Comment: Actually at high angles of attack it will be very noticeable.  You will require considerably more right rudder to coordinate a steep turn.

Comment: For most propeller driven aircraft designs the propeller shaft is parallel with the direction of flight eliminating (or nearly so) P-factor.  Only a poorly engineered aircraft would require rudder deflection (and resultant useless drag) in level flight.

Comment: @757toga That is incorrect. The engine crankshaft is permanently oriented relative to the  longitudinal axis of the airplane.   The angle between this and the relative wind varies with angle of attack.  Consequently P factor varies as well.   P factor is going to be a function of propeller angle of attack and engine power settings, and not whether the airplane is in level flight or not.

Comment: @Carlo Felicione - a clarification is needed.  Of course the the crankshaft is permanently orientated along the long axis, and the AOA will drive the magnitude of P-factor.  My point is that when the a/c is flying S/L the crankshaft alignment is designed to virtually eliminate unnecessary yaw that needs to be offset by rudder deflection.  As the a/c slows or any other pitch change resulting in increase of AOA, P-factor will be present.  In S/L flight, at cruise AOA, properly trimmed a/c, no rudder deflection to offset P-factor is necessary. It's considered in the design of the A/C.

Comment: @CarloFelicione - Lastly, not to grind this discussion too far, but the minor amount of true P-factor at cruise creating some adverse yaw is not because the downwind rotating blade is at a higher AOA than the upward rotating blade, it's because, from a pure aerodynamic perspective, the downward rotating blade is (aerodynamically) going slightly faster than the upward rotating blade. Performance engineering inherent in good A/C designs, considers this issue and attempts to minimize any adverse/unnecessary drag.  Good info here: http://www.qmfc.org/school/asym.htm

Comment: No, that’s incorrect again.  Manufactures will do things like preset the alignment of engines on the airframe etc. to reduce the effects of P factor, torque, spiral slipstream, etc as much as possible, but it cannot cover all conditions perfectly, including straight and level flight, without additional use of rudder, which is why larger, more powerful twins are equipped with rudder trim.

Comment: I would never go so far as to say you are (without reservation) "incorrect,"  especially due to the complexity of aerodynamics.  My experience is different than yours . . . I guess we will have to disagree.

Comment: Consider what happens in slow flight.   You will have a great deal of left turning tendency in this regime and require quite a bit of right rudder to track a straight, even in straight and level flight.  Again aeronautical designers trying design an aircraft it offers a good performance characteristics in the majority of flight regimes, but compromises and trade off do have to be made

Comment: @757toga is right with regards to P-factor specifically. Remember the left-turning tendency comes from two major very different aerodynamic effects (plus a few minor ones and mechanical torque): P-factor arises when prop axis is not aligned with the wind (airspeed) (and yes, the core reason is blade speed difference), and spiral slipstream is always present when the prop is turning. Now, in most cases, even at low speed, the latter prevails over P-factor. In cruise, with prop nearly aligned with airflow, P-factor is totally negligible. But again, all that is not related to turn (the maneuver).

Comment: Left turning tendency is a combination of P-Factor, torque and spiral slipstream.